# Recovering a kernel from a system of equations

Tags: integration, systems-of-equations

Suppose $f\in C([0,\frac{3}{4}]^2)$ and

$$\begin{array}{rlr}\text{i.}& \int_0^{\frac{3}{4}-x} f(x,y)dy=-\frac{1}{2}x^2+\frac{9}{32}&\forall x\in [0,\frac{3}{4}]\\
\text{ii.}& \int_0^{\frac{3}{4}-y} f(x,y)dx= \frac{1}{2}y^2-y+\frac{15}{32}&\forall y\in [0,\frac{3}{4}]\\
\text{iii.}& 0\leq f(x,y)\leq 1\end{array}$$

Does the system of equations (i)-(iii) has a solution and how could I recover the kernel $f$?.

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE. I've formatted your question a little nicer (see the [edit history](http://math.stackexchange.com/posts/977201/revisions)). [tag:statistics] is inappropriate here and [tag:differential-equations] might be a little overkill. Feel free to re-add the latter though if they tend to be needed.

Comment: $f(x,y) = \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{3}(x-y)$ works, but I needed a bit of guessing to get there, and there are probably other less "nice" solutions.